# In type theory, why isn't $x = x' : X$ simply wrong?

Tags: type-theory

If $X$ is a set, then personally, I tend to think of the equality relation on $X$ as a function $X^2 \rightarrow \mathrm{Bool}.$ Following this intuition, think that if $x$ and $y$ are variables of type $X$, then $x=y$ should be a term of type $\mathrm{Bool}.$

However, in my attempts to get educated about type theory, I have often seen expressions like

$$x = x' : X$$

where $X$ isn't the Boolean domain, nor even a poset.

Why aren't expressions like this just... wrong?

Comment: This is part of the syntax of type theory. Note that this is _not_ a proposition, so it does not have a truth value.

Comment: Could you point out where exactly you saw notation?

Comment: @AlešBizjak, page 7 of [Pitts](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cl.cam.ac.uk%2Ftechreports%2FUCAM-CL-TR-367.ps.gz&ei=JlWgUsmsE-yZiQerooHoDA&usg=AFQjCNFKo8aA9gqvXQhlXYPWkduBpthVOw&sig2=wrcTfO_biD7aEjdt83huRg&bvm=bv.57155469,d.aGc) is close at hand.

Comment: Can you explain what about it is wrong to you? There's no function type involved, so I'm not sure why you would take issue with a domain or codomain...

Comment: $x = x' : X$ should _not_ be read as $(x = x') : X$.

Comment: I agree. $x = y : z$ is just one more overloaded notation in mathematics. It can be the case $x = _ X y$ where $= _ X$ is a judgement, not a predicate, in type inference. Or it can be the case that $x = y : \textrm{Prop}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of $x = x' : X$ in Pitts' chapter you cite is not to say that $x = x'$ is of type $X$, but rather $x = x' : X$ is just notation for "equality in context" which is supposed to mean that $x$ and $x'$ are equal terms of type $X$. The whole construct $x = x' : X$ is assigned no type since he's considering only equational logic at that point but it could have type $\mathrm{Prop}$, the type of propositions.

In type theory you have two different notions of equality. The judgement $M \equiv M' : X$ which means that $M$ and $M'$ are convertible terms of type $X$. But this judgement has no type, it's a notion external to type theory. To talk about equality inside type theory one can define propositional, internal equality. Then given a type $X$ and $x, x'$ of type $X$ one can form a new type $x =_X x'$.

For instance in case of Coq, this type itself has type $\mathrm{Prop}$, the type of propositions. In case of Agda, this type can have type $\mathrm{Set}$, the type of all "small" types.

This is explained very well in the first chapter of the [HOTT book](http://homotopytypetheory.org/book/)

Comment: Are you specifically describing *homotopy* type theory?

Comment: No. I reference the HOTT book since it has a nice introduction to identity types in general.

Comment: And $x =_X x'$ is a type whose inhabitants you can think of as proofs of the fact that $x$ and $x'$ are equal. But, if the type theory is sufficiently rich then types are also terms of some higher type, so in that sense $x =_X x'$ is also a term. This is the case in Coq, for instance.